# Gibt es Dialekt-Wörterbücher?

Tags: translation, resource, dictionary

Gibt es Dialekt-Wörterbücher, also Wörterbücher für z. B. Deutsch–Bayrisch oder Bayrisch–Hessisch?
Wenn ja, welche könnt ihr empfehlen?

Comment: Related: [Is there an online German dialect dictionary?](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/349/is-there-an-online-german-dialect-dictionary)

Comment: I deleted my "dupe" comment, since that one is not a duplicate, but a related question.

Comment: @Alenanno: Ich habe meinen Kommentar auch gelöscht, wobei ich es gar nicht sarkastisch meinte.

Comment: Ah ok, no problem. :) By the way, I use both paper and digital dictionaries eheheh

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Die sind zwar eher scherzhaft gemeint, aber die **[Langenscheidt Lilliput Wörterbücher](http://www.langenscheidt.de/reihe/73/Langenscheidt_Lilliput-Woerterbuecher)** sind glaub ich gar nicht so schlecht. Zumindest sind sie sehr preiswert. ;-)

Es gibt davon Deutsch -

- Badisch
- Bairisch
- Berlinerisch
- Fränkisch
- Hessisch
- Kölsch
- Plattdeutsch
- Ruhrpott-Deutsch
- Schweizerdeutsch
- Schwäbisch
- Sächsisch
- Wienerisch

Comment: Die sind ja winzig. Wusste gar nicht, dass es da Dialektwörterbücher gibt, hübsche Idee :)

Answer (score 3):

Die Bücher von [Otto Hietsch](http://www.amazon.com/Otto-Hietsch/e/B001I7QI00/ref=ntt_athr_dp_pel_pop_1) sind sehr hilfreich.

Für Bairisch gibt es: *Bavarian into English: A lexical and cultural guide*. Es gibt "Volume One" und "Volume Two", auch wenn Amazon nicht das zweite Buchband nennt.

Für Österreichisch gibt es: *From "anbandeln" to "Zwetschkenknodel: An Austrian lexical and cultural guide*

Answer (score 3):

Ich verweise mal auf [Bairisch – das echte Hochdeutsch – Wort für Wort](http://www.reise-know-how.de/kauderwelsch-buch_bairisch-das-echte-hochdeutsch-wort-fuer-wort-p-302.html) . Ich kenne diesen Band zwar nicht persönlich, kenne aber viele andere Bände der [Kauderwelsch Reihe](http://www.reise-know-how.de/kauderwelsch-buch-c-208_221.html).

Weitere Dialekte und Deutsch für Fremdsprachler aus der Reihe findest du [hier](http://www.reise-know-how.de/kauderwelsch-buch-c-208_221.html?filter_land_id=68&filter_manufacturer_id=29).

Worte, die unser voreiliger Oberzensor vermutlich (vielleicht zu ich ihm ja auch unrecht) als obszön einstufen könnte, sollten [hier](http://www.reise-know-how.de/kauderwelsch-buch_german-slang-the-real-german-wort-fuer-wort-p-367.html) zu finden sein.

Der Anspruch der Reihe liegt darin, sich mit ökonomischem Arbeitseinsatz auf praktische Konversationssituationen vorzubereiten. Audiomaterial gibt es auch.

Ich schätze die Bücher der Reihe für diesen Zweck als sehr hilfreich ein. Ich denke auch, dass sie Studierenden, die ein höheres Sprachniveau anstreben, etwas bringen können.

Answer (score 1):

Als ich in Bayern war, hat mir meine Gastfamilie die Langenscheidt Bairisch-Hochdeutsch Wörterbuch geschenkt.  Hat mir auch sehr geholfen und ich empfehle es. :)

Comment: Welcome to German Language & Usage on Stackexchange! There is absolutely nothing wrong with your comment, except that it should be, well, a comment instead of an Answer. Hope you find this website to be useful and fun :)

Comment: Thanks!  I thought it would pass since OP asked for recommendations and I included that I (both received and) recommend the Langenscheidt dictionary.  I'll try to be more specific next time!