# Does "passt scho" mean "passt so" or "passt schon"?

Tags: meaning, dialect, bavarian, contractions

People say "passt scho" here all the time. Does that mean "passt so" or ["passt schon"](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/150/what-can-passt-schon-mean)? Is there any difference between using "passt scho" and whichever of those two it means?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It does mean "passt schon" and is simply Bavarian dialect. The "n" is just missing.

"Passt so" is afaik only used when it comes to money (when you disclaim your change). You can use "Passt schon" in this situation, too. But not vice versa.

Comment: "passt scho" Is also used a lot in the Swiss-German part of Switzerland.

Comment: I disagree with the second paragraph: "passt scho", originating from "passt schon", means "it's okay" and can be used in many situations, while "passt so" is the phrase that would be used in the context with money, like giving a tip. To make things even more complicated, "passt scho" may also be used in the sense of "passt so", but not vice versa. :-)

Answer (score 10):

I think people use it more in Bavaria. It is "passt schon", but it is used more like "it's okay" or "everything is fine" or even sometimes "whatever".

e.g.:

1. A: Bist du krank? B: passt scho'! (means maybe he's sick or not, but it doesn't bother him)
2. A: How's your work? B: passt scho'! (it's a more positive okay)
3. A: Sorry, I'm late! B: passt scho'!

And I always heard the bayrisch pronounce it "basst scho'!" with "B" instead of "P"

Comment: Thanks! I had never noticed the /b/; I'll be more observant next time I'm in Bavaria.